# Python 2.7: some drawing work then save to image file?

Tags: python, image, drawing

I am new to Python and need some help.

I need to read data from a file, say some (x, y) data, then plot them and draw some lines, as well as some text output, on a X-Y coordinate system. Then I need to save the image to a file (PNG, JPG or BMP, don't care about format).

Can somebody give some suggestion/directions? Thanks a lot.

-Nick

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248812/matplotlib-basic-plotting-from-text-file

Comment: Another post is helpful for my question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289679/python-create-image-with-multiple-colors-and-add-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. I finally finish my work using these functions:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import htmltag

import csv

plt.clf()

...

plt.savefig

...

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

...

output = open("a.html","w")

output.write(text)

output.close()

Answer (score 0):

for read data from file, you need only read the guide of [python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

for the save [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452824/saving-image-in-python-pil)

Comment: Thanks. I found this post is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289679/python-create-image-with-multiple-colors-and-add-text